# Messing with drop shadows in IE

Tags: jquery, css

i have created an example of a drop box shadow and a hover image, which seems to be working fine, apart from the usual problem, internet explerror. You can check the fiddle here :

[www.jsfiddle.net/kcD6j/3/](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kcD6j/3/)

To handle ie7 and ie8 i have tried to do different things, from directly adding ms-filter attributes to including ie-css3 (cannot reproduce with jsfiddle,no cross domain htc allowed i think). The style i added was like :

```
.box-shadow {
  behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
}
```

It presents a shadow, but it's totally black(not fading as the original) and more importantly, if covers part of the image frame, on the rightest side and thus shows really ugly.

Does anyone have an idea on how this can be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out this Website yet ?
http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/16/drop-shadow-with-css-for-all-web-browsers/
There is something like

```
.shadow {
/* For IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135,   color='#000000');
}
```

maybe this could be your solution.

Comment: i actually refer to that in my question, but it seems that the border or something kills it. It shows really bad.